# How to best implement a shareable data model in Svelte views

Tags: model, svelte, svelte-store

I have a View that I created that contains a form, that form's controls being bound to the properties on a Model object, which is shared by other views as well).  I am trying to figure out if using the Store paradigm is really necessary or recommended.

For example the model would look kinda like :

```
model = { 
   foo: undefined,
   bar: undefined,
   baz: undefined
}
```

... and the UI would have various inputs bound to the model via something like this:

```
//example.svelte
<script>
   import { exampleModel } from "./models.js";
</script>

<h2>Has foo?</h2>
<label for="input_foo_t">yes</label>
<input id="input_foo_t" type="radio" bind:group={exampleModel.foo} value={true}/>

<label for="input_foo_f">no</label>
<input id="input_foo_f" type="radio" bind:group={exampleModel.foo} value={false}/>

<h2>Has bar?</h2>
<label for="input_bar_t">yes</label>
<input id="input_bar_t" type="radio" bind:group={exampleModel.bar} value={true}/>

<label for="input_bar_f">no</label>
<input id="input_bar_f" type="radio" bind:group={exampleModel.bar} value={false}/>
```

Ideally I would like to keep theses as a whole unit.  From all the examples I see there isn't anything like this out there.  Is the intent of the Svelte Stores to provide super granular, shareable data such that we're basically "storing" a single value?  Or are there examples out there that show something like a Model object being used within the store paradigm?  Am I missing some life cycle process that I need to take advantage of by using the Svelte Store (akin to say Angular's digest)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You certainly *can* use a store for this:

```js
// models.js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const exampleModel = writable({
  foo: undefined,
  bar: undefined,
  baz: undefined,
});
```

```html
//example.svelte
<script>
   import { exampleModel } from "./models.js";
</script>

<h2>Has foo?</h2>
<label for="input_foo_t">yes</label>
<input id="input_foo_t" type="radio" bind:group={$exampleModel.foo} value={true}/>
<!-- etc -->
```

Having said that, it's better not to have *huge* models, because modifying one property will cause all dependencies of it to be checked (i.e. if you change `$exampleModel.foo`, references to `$exampleModel.bar` will also be updated because as far as Svelte is concerned `$exampleModel` is the thing that changed). That's not a generally a real problem, but it's something to be aware of. The alternative, which avoids that, is to have more granular values:

```js
// models.js
export const foo = writable();
export const bar = writable();
export const baz = writable();
```

Comment: So is there any real advantage to using the Svelte store for my models?  I mean I can easily achieve the same thing via a simple export of the model object and it still reflects the changes in the other views that consume it.

Comment: If it reflects those changes somehow, it does so by accident. In Svelte, the way to manage data outside the component hierarchy is to use stores

Answer (score 1):

I have created two examples that demonstrate what Rich is talking about.

1. The first uses a single model (with depth) holding all three variables *(demo here: [Svelte Store Granularity (Ver 1 Single Model)](https://svelte.dev/repl/01252a9527dc4cef97d379b6da4ef0f6?version=3.23.2))*.

   Click a checkbox to change the individual variable.  The tallied state changes *(to the right)* show that all three variables are **incorrectly** considered to have been reflectively changed :-(

   ```js
   <script>
     const fooChangeCount = createReflectiveCounter();
     const barChangeCount = createReflectiveCounter();
     const bazChangeCount = createReflectiveCounter();

     // monitor store-based state changes
     $: fooChangeCount.monitor($model.foo);
     $: barChangeCount.monitor($model.bar);
     $: bazChangeCount.monitor($model.baz);

     const reset = () => {
       fooChangeCount.reset();
       barChangeCount.reset();
       bazChangeCount.reset();
     };
   </script>

   <h2>Svelte Store Granularity</h2>
   <h4><i>(Ver 1 Single Model)</i></h4>

   <label><input type=checkbox bind:checked={$model.foo}> foo: (state changed {$fooChangeCount} times)</label>
   <label><input type=checkbox bind:checked={$model.bar}> bar: (state changed {$barChangeCount} times)</label>
   <label><input type=checkbox bind:checked={$model.baz}> baz: (state changed {$bazChangeCount} times)</label>

   <p><i>click to change each var: <b>state changes tallied to right</b></i></p>
   <button on:click={reset}>Reset Counts</button>

   <script context="module">
     import {writable} from 'svelte/store';

     const model = writable({
       foo: undefined,
       bar: undefined,
       baz: undefined,
     });

     function createReflectiveCounter() {
       // our base writable store
       // ... -1 accounts for our initial monitor reflection (bumping it to 0)
       const {subscribe, set, update} = writable(-1);

       // expose our newly created custom store
       return {
         subscribe,
         monitor() {
           update((count) => count + 1); // increment our count
           return '';                    // see JavaDoc
         },
         reset: () => set(0)
       };
     }
   </script>
   ```
2. The second uses a multiple models, one for each of the three variables *(demo here: [Svelte Store Granularity (Ver 2 Multiple Models)](https://svelte.dev/repl/8975ffa54b274e1fbc32b6b114dccca4?version=3.23.2))*.

   In this case the tallied state changes *(to the right)* now **correctly** show that only the variable that actually changed is considered to be reflexive :-)

   ```js
   <script>
     const fooChangeCount = createReflectiveCounter();
     const barChangeCount = createReflectiveCounter();
     const bazChangeCount = createReflectiveCounter();

     // monitor store-based state changes
     $: fooChangeCount.monitor($foo);
     $: barChangeCount.monitor($bar);
     $: bazChangeCount.monitor($baz);

     const reset = () => {
       fooChangeCount.reset();
       barChangeCount.reset();
       bazChangeCount.reset();
     };
   </script>


   <h2>Svelte Store Granularity</h2>
   <h4><i>(Ver 2 Multiple Models)</i></h4>

   <label><input type=checkbox bind:checked={$foo}> foo: (state changed {$fooChangeCount} times)</label>
   <label><input type=checkbox bind:checked={$bar}> bar: (state changed {$barChangeCount} times)</label>
   <label><input type=checkbox bind:checked={$baz}> baz: (state changed {$bazChangeCount} times)</label>

   <!-- Diagnostic: monitor store-based state changes -->
   <p><i>click to change each var: <b>state changes tallied to right</b></i></p>
   <button on:click={reset}>Reset Counts</button>


   <script context="module">
     import {writable} from 'svelte/store';

     const foo = writable();
     const bar = writable();
     const baz = writable();

     function createReflectiveCounter() {
       // our base writable store
       // ... -1 accounts for our initial monitor reflection (bumping it to 0)
       const {subscribe, set, update} = writable(-1);

       // expose our newly created custom store
       return {
         subscribe,
         monitor() {
           update((count) => count + 1); // increment our count
           return '';                    // see JavaDoc
         },
         reset: () => set(0)
       };
     }
   </script>
   ```

Hope this helps!

`</Kevin>`